# Maven error: could not find artifact h2:h2:jar:1.3.167 in internal

Tags: apache, maven

I am trying to build a Maven project with the following command line:

"mvn -U clean install"

and I keep getting this error:

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/h2/h2/1.3.167/h2-1.3.167.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 38.547s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 04 10:23:13 CST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 42M/64M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project GenManagerEar: Could not resolve depen
dencies for project PCI:GenManagerEar:ear:5.2.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifac
t h2:h2:jar:1.3.167 in internal (http://buildmachine:8080/archiva/repository/int
ernal)
```

In my local repository I have this for h2:

[image]

It looks like it can't download the h2 JAR file. Why is that?

Answer (score 0):

You coordinates of the h2 database artifact seemed to be wrong.

Based on [maven central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.h2database%7Ch2%7C1.3.170%7Cjar) they should be:

```
groupId: com.h2database
artifactId: h2
version: 1.3.170
```

Furthermore your configuration using the internal Archiva seemed to be wrong as well, cause usually if you are using a repository manager no access to maven central directly should be done.

Comment: I think that fixed the issue, and i just noticed our lead developer completely took out h2 from the POM for the project in question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will happen if incase the version of your local repository is differ from the `POM.xm`l version (`<version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>`). Please check in `.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.197`. If jar not present, download the actual JAR from maven repository.